# Get <img>'s title-attribute with lxml in Python

Tags: python, dom, xpath, html-parsing, lxml

I want to extract the onel-iner-texts from [this](http://www.scenemusic.net/demovibes/oneliner/) website using Python. The messages in HTML look like this:

```html
<div class="olh_message"> 
    <p>foobarbaz <img src="/static/emoticons/support-our-fruits.gif" title=":necta:" /></p> 
</div>
```

My code looks like this so far:

```python
import lxml.html
url = "http://www.scenemusic.net/demovibes/oneliner/"
xpath = "//div[@class='olh_message']/p"
tree = lxml.html.parse(url)
texts = tree.xpath(xpath)
texts = [text.text_content() for text in texts]
print(texts)
```

Now, however, I only get `foobarbaz`, I however would like to get the title-argument of the img's in it as well, so in this example `foobarbaz :necta:`. It seems I need lxml's DOM parser to do it, however I have no idea how. Anyone can give me a hint?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```python
  import lxml.html
  url = "http://www.scenemusic.net/demovibes/oneliner/"
  parser = lxml.etree.HTMLParser()
  tree = lxml.etree.parse(url, parser)
  texts = tree.xpath("//div[@class='olh_message']/p/img/@title")
```

Comment: Thanks, however I want to have the text including the title-attributes (like `foo <img title="bar">...</img> baz` -> `foo bar baz`)

Comment: the xpath I told you + the xpath you originally posted won't do the job?

Comment: Let me try to clarify: I want to have the text I get with my example, with the emoticons in the right places. So, for example, if I have this HTML: [paste](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/435084/) I want to have this final result: `['one :) two :D three', 'blah bluh blah']`

Comment: Sorry for the double post... In other words, you could say I want to replace every img-node inside `//div[@class='olh_message']/p` with it's title-attribute.

Comment: @The Compiler: when you want to clarify what you are asking, please do that by editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
//div[@class='olh_message']/p/node()
```

his selects all children nodes (elements, text-nodes, PIs and comment-nodes) of any `p` element that is a child of any `div` element, whose `class` attribute is `'olh_message'`.

**Verification using XSLT as the host of XPath**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="//div[@class='olh_message']/p/node()"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<div class="olh_message">
    <p>foobarbaz 
        <img src="/static/emoticons/support-our-fruits.gif" title=":necta:" />
    </p>
</div>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced** (showing that exactly the wanted nodes have been selected by the XPath expression):

```
foobarbaz 
        <img src="/static/emoticons/support-our-fruits.gif" title=":necta:"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, however this isn't really what I want. See my comments on the previous answer, this should make it clear.

Comment: @The Compiler: You must edit your question: this changes its meaning and makes it a new, very different question. For the *current* question my answer provides the exact and correct solution. Also, if you are asking a second question, it is only fare and logical not to play with the people who answered the first one and to downgrade their answers to nothing. Your second question is very easy to answer (though it requires not only XPath), but I will be reluctant to delete my answer to the first question, because it is also valuable to people. How do i know you won't change the question again?

Comment: No, it doesn't change the question, you just mis-interpreted it. The question clearly states that the output should include the `title` 'argument' of the `img` tag ('attribute' would have been more accurate, but it's pretty obvious), and even provided the expected output that included just `:necta:` without the `img` element. Your answer's still partially valid, it's just incomplete. You just need to output the value of the attribute, for example `concat(//div[@class='olh_message']/p/text(),//div[@class='olh_message']/p/img/@title)'.

Comment: @Flynn1179: My answer produces exactly what the OP says he wants -- in his first comment to @user835846. Any question that is "evolving" in this way will never have a "correct" answer.